# Exception:execute_cql3_query failed: out of sequence response

Tags: cassandra

i tried cassandra for storing the data but stucked with inserting huge data, my problem is like this:
i am inserting Data into cassandra using Insert Query, i have huge data stored into file, so i am reading the file Line by line and uinserting into cassandra, but i am geeting this Exception:

```
execute_cql3_query failed: out of sequence response

query = "insert into " + tableName[0]
        + "(sn,ts,dn,ma,br,re,ds,oi,lo,cl) values " + "('"
        + entry.getSn() + "'," + entry.getTs() + ",'"
        + entry.getDn() + "','" + entry.getMa() + "','"
        + entry.getBr() + "','" + entry.getRe() + "','"
        + entry.getDs() + "','" + entry.getOi() + "','"
        + entry.getLo() + "','" + entry.getCl() + "')"; 


can u please help me out?
```

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: @TylerHobbs can u help me?

Comment: Is there a missing space before '(sn'?